# Listbox formatting VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox, formatting, format

I would like to format my listbox so that the output becomes something like this.

[image]

This is method, not in the main form tho:

```
Public Function GetSeatInfoStrings(ByVal choice As DisplayOptions,
                                      ByRef strSeatInfoStrings As String()) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = GetNumOfSeats(choice)

    If (count <= 0) Then
        Return 0
    End If

    strSeatInfoStrings = New String(count - 1) {}

    Dim StrReservation As String = ""

    strSeatInfoStrings = New String(count - 1) {}

    Dim i As Integer = 0 'counter for return array 

    'is the element corresponding with the index empty 
    For index As Integer = 0 To m_totNumOfSeats - 1

        Dim strName As String = ""
        Dim reserved As Boolean = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_nameList(index))

        'if the criteria below are not met, skip to add info in the array
        If (choice = DisplayOptions.AllSeats) Or
            (reserved And choice = DisplayOptions.ReservedSeats) Or
            ((Not reserved) And (choice = DisplayOptions.VacantSeats)) Then

            If (reserved) Then
                StrReservation = "Reserved"
                strName = m_nameList(index)
            Else
                StrReservation = "Vacant"
                strName = "..........."
            End If

            strSeatInfoStrings(i) = String.Format("{0,4}  {1,-8} {2, -20} {3,10:f2}",
                                                  index + 1, StrReservation, strName, m_priceList(index))
            i += 1
        End If

    Next
    Return count

End Function
```

I don't know how to format the listbox as the strSeatInfoStrings(i) in the main form.
My listbox

This is what I've done

```
Private Sub UpdateGUI()
    'Clear the listbox and make it ready for new data.
    ReservationList.Items.Clear()

    'size of array is determined in the callee method
    Dim seatInfoStrings As String() = Nothing
    Dim calcOption As DisplayOptions = DirectCast(cmbDisplayOptions.SelectedIndex, DisplayOptions)

    Dim count As Integer = m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(calcOption, seatInfoStrings)

    If count > 0 Then
        ReservationList.Items.AddRange(seatInfoStrings)
    Else
        ReservationList.Items.Add("Nothing to display!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error! I forgot to call the UpdateGUI() in the IntializeGUI().